# Add InterceptionBehaviour to everything registered in the IoC Container

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a Unity container with many registrations in it, these registrations are intercepted for logging.

Is there a way I can greedily add the Interceptor to *every* registration?  It's feeling like `Ctrl-C, Ctrl+V` overload.

```
var container =  new UnityContainer();

container
    .AddNewExtension<Interception>()
    .RegisterType<IDummy1, Dummy1>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), loggingInterceptionBehavior)
    .RegisterType<IDummy2, Dummy2>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), loggingInterceptionBehavior)
    .RegisterType<IDummy3, Dummy3>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), loggingInterceptionBehavior)
    .RegisterType<IDummy4, Dummy4>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), loggingInterceptionBehavior)
    .RegisterType<IDummy5, Dummy5>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), loggingInterceptionBehavior)
```

I've seen the following example [here](http://mohtasebi.com/patterns/2013/10/24/using-unity-for-aspect-oriented-programming-and-interception-part-1.html), using XML config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
    <!-- Using Interception -->
    <container name="Interception">
      <extension type="Interception" />
      <register type="AopTest.ILogger, AopTest" mapTo="AopTest.Logger, AopTest" />
      <register type="AopTest.ICalculator, AopTest" mapTo="AopTest.Calculator, AopTest" />
      <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor" />
      <interceptionBehavior type="Infrastructure.LoggingInterceptionBehavior, Infrastructure" />
    </register>
  </container>
</configuration>
```

Which I assume registers the `Infrastructure.LoggingInterceptionBehavior` for both `AopTest.ILogger` and `AopTest.ICalculator`. (?)

How could I do this in code?

Comment: The link sample is using name matching rule. There is another one that uses namespace matching rule (NamespaceMatchingRule). You can register your main namespace and all registered implementations under that namespace will be intercepted.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [convention based registrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx), so you can register all those types using a convention and add the interception behaviour a single time:

```
var container = new UnityContainer()
        .AddNewExtension<Interception>()        
        .RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(IDummy1).Assembly),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
            getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[]
            {
                new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
                new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptor>()
            });
```

The `WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface` convention will register any types where the names follow the convention that given an interface `IService` the class implementing it is named `Service`. So you could now resolve any of `IDummy1`, `IDummy2`, `IFoo` etc and the `LoggingInterceptor` behaviour would be applied.

You can try a sample in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4KjPY)

**EDIT**: Just to clarify it, as BanksySAN commented this is only available in Unity >= 3. For Unity 2 there might be external packages for convention based configuration like [this one](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration) which might be helpful but I haven't tried them myself. Worst case you could roll your own code...

Comment: Thanks Daniel, unfortunately for me, we're using Unity 2 and that feature is Unity 3.  I suppose I can make a registration helper method to do it.

Comment: `IUnityContainer.RegisterTypes` doesn't exist any more in the Unity 5.7 !!!